# Which Subversion is bundled with Perl 5.8.8?

Tags: perl, svn, version, msysgit, perl5.8

It seems to me that [`msysGit` uses Perl 5.8.8](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/search?q=subversion&ref=cmdform).

Accordingly to [upgrade Subversion](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/I-want-to-upgrade-Subversion.-How-do-I-do-that) I would like to know:

- which Perl/Subversion bindings is bundled with Perl 5.8.8?
- which Subversion version is bundled with Perl 5.8.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No version of Subversion is bundled with any version of Perl. No Perl/Subversion bindings are bundled with any version of Perl either.

Comment: So, if I have understood right, the Perl/Subversion bindings cited in how to [upgrade Subversion](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/I-want-to-upgrade-Subversion.-How-do-I-do-that) should be ```msysGit``` software written in Perl from scratch, right?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that they mean one of [the many SVN modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=svn) available on CPAN. I guess you could look through the [git source](https://github.com/git/git) to see what they use.

Comment: Yes, it should: [the "Perl/Subversion bindings" is part of ```msysGit```](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/tree/ab173bb3bc3852b04e2958abac61bc6f65c7a64a/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys/SVN). Thanks!